# Relation between IsAssembly / IsFamily and IsFamilyOrAssembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, assemblies, system.reflection

**`IsAssembly, IsPublic, IsFamily, IsFamilyOrAssembly, IsFamilyAndAssembly`** I have read about this but I am not able to understand what each one does. The strange thing here is **`IsFamily`** and **`IsAssembly`** returns `False` in the code but **`IsFamilyOrAssembly`** returns `True`.

Can someone give an explanation for each of this property as I find it difficult to understand from the documentation.I came across all this when I started reading about Reflection in c#.

```
public class Example
{
    public void m_public() {}
    internal void m_internal() {}
    protected void m_protected() {}
    protected internal void m_protected_public() {}

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n{0,-30}{1,-18}{2}", "", "IsAssembly", "IsFamilyOrAssembly"); 
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-21}{1,-18}{2,-18}{3}\n", 
            "", "IsPublic", "IsFamily", "IsFamilyAndAssembly");

        foreach (MethodBase m in typeof(Example).GetMethods(
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            if (m.Name.Substring(0, 1) == "m")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-21}{1,-9}{2,-9}{3,-9}{4,-9}{5,-9}", 
                    m.Name,
                    m.IsPublic,
                    m.IsAssembly,
                    m.IsFamily,
                    m.IsFamilyOrAssembly,
                    m.IsFamilyAndAssembly
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code example produces output similar to the following:

> ```
>                               IsAssembly        IsFamilyOrAssembly
>                      IsPublic          IsFamily          IsFamilyAndAssembly
>
> m_public             True     False    False    False    False
> m_internal           False    True     False    False    False
> m_protected          False    False    True     False    False
> m_protected_public   False    False    False    True     False
> ```

Comment: Can you invert the question? What information are you looking for exactly, and why do you think these properties will provide it?

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't know how else to modify this. I need to know the functionality of this and where it can be applied and whats the difference between them

Comment: You now discovered those properties are mutually exclusive and correspond to certain combinations of access modifiers. What more do you need to know? Also, why did you copy the code from MSDN but not run it? The output does not match the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Member of a Class have access modifiers associated with them (public, internal,...). These define the level of object-oriented encapsulation implemented by the member. You can find more details at [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).

Using Reflection, you might want to have a look at:

```
                    /*Modifiers*/

IsPublic            public

IsFamilyOrAssembly  protected internal

IsFamily            protected

IsFamilyAndAssembly private protected (since C# 7.2)

IsAssembly          internal
```

When you want to determine if a member is visible in inherited types, you need to check using the expression (**m.IsFamilyOrAssembly** || **m.IsFamily** || **m.IsFamilyAndAssembly** || **m.IsAssembly**). And exactly only one of these properties is **true** and all of the others are **false**.

Answer (score 0):

These methods check for certain enumeration values from the [`MethodAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration. Unfortunately, this is a rather complex enum type. If we examine it's [early values](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/methodattributes.cs,16):

```
public enum MethodAttributes
{
    // NOTE: This Enum matchs the CorMethodAttr defined in CorHdr.h

    // member access mask - Use this mask to retrieve accessibility information.
    MemberAccessMask    =   0x0007,
    PrivateScope        =   0x0000,     // Member not referenceable.
    Private             =   0x0001,     // Accessible only by the parent type.  
    FamANDAssem         =   0x0002,     // Accessible by sub-types only in this Assembly.
    Assembly            =   0x0003,     // Accessibly by anyone in the Assembly.
    Family              =   0x0004,     // Accessible only by type and sub-types.    
    FamORAssem          =   0x0005,     // Accessibly by sub-types anywhere, plus anyone in assembly.
    Public              =   0x0006,     // Accessibly by anyone who has visibility to this scope.    
    // end member access mask
    ...
```

We can observe that `FamORAssem` and `FamANDAssem` are distinct values, and they are not related to the `Family` or `Assembly` values. Confusingly, this enum is marked with the `Flags` attribute, but when it comes to the member access values, they're not simple bitwise combinations.